# I need fillcolor to read value in Python

Tags: python, function

I am setting up two definitions and I want the fillColor to read from the drawBar. The program is not reading the correct color corresponding to the value.

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()             # Set up the window
wn.bgcolor("white")

tess = turtle.Turtle()  
tess.penup()
tess.goto(-100,-75)
tess.pendown()


def drawBar(t, height):
    """ Get turtle t to draw one bar, of height. """
    t.left(90) 
    t.begin_fill()# Point up
    t.forward(height)
    # Draw up the left side
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(40)            # width of bar, along the top
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(height) 
    t.end_fill()# And down again!
    t.left(90)   

def drawColor(t, height):
    drawBar(t, height)
    if height >= 200:
         return tess.fillcolor("red")
    elif height  < 200 and v >= 100:
         return tess.fillcolor("yellow")
    elif height < 100: 
         return tess.fillcolor("green")

xs = [48, 117, 200, 240, 160, 260, 220]

for v in xs:                 # assume xs and tess are ready
    drawColor(tess, v)
```

I dont know why this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have a typo when you are referring to the `height` tests:

```
elif height  < 200 and v >= 100:
     return tess.fillcolor("yellow")
```

Should probably be:

```
elif 100 <= height < 200:
     return tess.fillcolor("yellow")
```

`v` is probably being found in the global scope and not what you wanted to test.

Also, you are passing in the reference to the turtle object, but you aren't using it:

```
def drawColor(t, height):
    drawBar(t, height)
    if height >= 200:
         # return tess.fillcolor("red")
         return t.fillcolor("red")
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `drawColor` to:

```
def drawColor(t, height):    
    if height >= 200:
         t.fillcolor("red")
    elif height  < 200 and height >= 100:
         t.fillcolor("yellow")
    elif height < 100: 
         t.fillcolor("green")
    drawBar(t, height)
```

This way you are first setting the right color with respect to the current height and then plot the bar. In your original code you are drawing a bar with the current color (starting with the default color black) and after that changing the color to draw, so every new bar is drawn in the color the last one should have.

In your original code there are some other problems too. You don't use the passed turtle object `t` but the global one `tess`. There's also no need to return the result of the `fillcolor` calls.